# I am updating springboot version from 2.1.1 to 2.6.4

Tags: spring-boot

I get this error after the upgarde:

```
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/arikashr/project/getswish/swish-mts/core/src/main/java/se/bgc/swish/mts/db/changelogs/DatabaseChangelogV1_0.java:\[6,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DB
[ERROR]   location: package com.mongodb
[ERROR] /mnt/c/Users/arikashr/project/getswish/swish-mts/core/src/main/java/se/bgc/swish/mts/db/changelogs/DatabaseChangelogV1_0.java:\[17,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DB
[ERROR]   location: class se.bgc.swish.mts.db.changelogs.DatabaseChangelogV1_0
```

seems like it is not able to find the package after the version upgrade.

I am have been trying to upgrade to minimum versions and solve the dependency issues. But now i am stuck since its not able to find the package after upgrade

Comment: Show your source code of `DatabaseChangelogV1_0.java`.

Comment: import com.github.mongobee.changeset.ChangeLog;
import com.github.mongobee.changeset.ChangeSet;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.bson.Document;

@ChangeLog(order = "001")
public class DatabaseChangelogV1_0 {

    @ChangeSet(order = "001", id = "1.0-1-cleanup", author = "Nguyen")
    public void cleanUp(DB db) {
        db.getCollection("merchant").remove(new BasicDBObject());
    }
}

Comment: No, edit your question, then paste your code to the question.